# $.scrollTo(this.hash || 0, 1500); ? what is the meaning of numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollto

`$.scrollTo(this.hash || 0, 1500);`

In this code, what is the meaning of `0, 1500`?

I was trying to make smooth scrolling to `#URL` in tag `a`.

I can understand why I have to use `this.hash`, but I can't understand the part about `0, 1500`. Please help me.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('nav a').click(function(e){
            $.scrollTo(this.hash || 0, 1500);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: these x and y cords, read here [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: `,` separates arguments passed to functions. `this.hash || 0` is the first argument, `1500` is the second one.

Comment: It meas this: `$.scrollTo((this.hash || 0), 1500)`, not this: `$.scrollTo(this.hash || (0, 1500))`, don't let it confuse you.

Comment: ah thank you!:) And then, what is the meaning of 'this.hash||0', and '1500' each?

Comment: 1. check this out https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo
2. `this.hash||0` denotes the target where it will scroll to and `1500` denotes animation duration 
3. `this.hash||0` - It means if this.hash is false, then 0 will be default. Don't ask me what is `this.hash` :)

Comment: window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)